# objective c: exchange cell across sections

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview contain many sections, in each of section, there is one cell, what I want to do is, when enter the editing mode, I will drag and drop one cell to another section, and I wish when drag is finished, the origin cell in target section will auto exchange to the section which the cell moved out.

Here's the code I did test, but didn't work

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath 
{
    NSInteger destRow=destinationIndexPath.row;
    NSInteger srcRow=0;
    NSIndexPath *srcIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:srcRow inSection:destinationIndexPath.section];
    UITableViewCell *cell=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:srcIndexPath];
    [cell.textLabel setText:@"aaa"];// test if I got right cell, the result is ok.

    NSIndexPath *trgIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:sourceIndexPath.section];
    [self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:srcIndexPath toIndexPath:trgIndexPath];
}
```

Kindly help me to check if there is any solutions, thanks!

Comment: Clarify what doesn't work. What actually happens?

Comment: if I move cell from section 2 to section 1 any where, the cell in section 1 will disappeared, the same thing would be occurred if I move cell in section 1 to section 2